# ApplicationPool user vs StartInfo.Username?

Tags: c#, iis, process, iis-7.5, w3wp

*I've been testing ( for the last 4 days) the variety of options to start a Process under iis7 ( asp.net)*

I *did* find a solution.

As long as we *don't* need to interact with desktop, and only need to run `cmd` ( *or something like that*) the solution is simple:

1. `w3wp` user`->` should be *high* privileged user.
2. Process start info (`StartInfo.Username`)`->` should be *also* high privileged user.

However, there is a catch ( according to *my* testings):

> **Both** users have to be the same (if we want `cmd` to execute)! this is the only way it will work.

So here are my 2 questions:

- Why they both must be the same? Can't w3wp *HighPrivileged*`USerA` run (via process.startInfo) `cmd` as *HighPriviliged*`USerB`?
- Both users are domain admins.( which are also admins in my local group). Does only domain admin/local admin can run processes on the local machine?

*p.s. All folders permissions are `everyone : full controll` ( including `c:\windows\*.* /s` and including cmd.exe permissions) and both users, as mentioned, are admins on local machine with same cloned permissions.IIS7 handler mapping `*` [static file] is set to read+execute*

Also, the full cmd command is:

`cmd /c time /t >c:\1.txt`. A success is if the file exists.( and I succeed, only when both account were the same).

Full code:

```
Process proc = new Process();
  proc.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd";
  proc.StartInfo.UserName = "Royin"; //<-- only if this user is the same as w3wp user , the operation succeed !
  proc.StartInfo.Domain = ...;
  proc.StartInfo.WorkingFolder = @"c:\windows\system32";
  proc.StartInfo.Password = ...
  proc.StartInfo.Arguments = @"/c time /t >c:\1.txt"
  proc.Start();
```

Comment: A *web server* running with a highly privileged user account?  Looking to out-source your LAN's maintenance to a Chinese hacker?  This is not a C# question, you'll need a site like serverfault.com or webmasters.se

Comment: @HansPassant `StartInfo.Username`  is a C# class. there is a weird problem that both w3wp user and the username provided to ProcessStartInfo (c# class) should be the same. I can't see how serverfault.com can understand what is `StartInfo.Username`

Comment: `both w3wp user and the username provided to ProcessStartInfo (c# class) should be the same.` - should be the same in order to do what? What exactly are you trying to achieve? Could you show your code? Are you trying to run some process?

Comment: @DarinDimitrov in order for the `cmd` to execute.

Comment: cmd.exe will always be executed. You don't even need to be an administrator. But running cmd.exe is kinda meaningless per se. I guess you are trying to pass some parameters to this cmd.exe. Like for example some process name or some command. What exactly are you trying to do? What is the process supposed to do? What privileges does it need? Please provide more information about your scenario and what is your goal.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov `cmd` will _not_ always be executed. a web page (running under w3wp application pool user)  - which tries to run `Process.Start` with credentials will succees ( to my testings) only when both accounts are the same.

Comment: But how do you define *succeed* for a cmd.exe? As I said running only `cmd.exe` without any parameters isn't very meaningful. So I repeat my question: are you passing some parameters?

Comment: @DarinDimitrov `cmd /c time /t >c:\1.txt` - if the files exists. ( I didnt write the whole command. it isnot important what the cmd actually do. any way I clarified it in my question. thanks :-) ) p.s. this command is just an example.  In reality I Run PGP.exe. ( he also create file).

Comment: Alright, now that's much better. Thanks for providing this info. Now all that's left is to update your question and post the code you are using to start the process.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov Thank's . already updated. :-P

Comment: I still can't see any code. Why is your question tagged with C#? Do you have some code to share with us? The one that you are using to run the process would be particularly useful. Thanks.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov edited full code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, first, I HIGHLY recommend using the excellent SysInternals ProcessMonitor to help troubleshoot any issue like this: [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx).

This app will basically tell you every action a process is attempting to take, so in your situation, you'd see it try to call `QueryOpen`, `ProcessCreate`, etc.

Have you checked what the ExitCode of the process is under the failing scenario? I'd be willing to bet real money it's coming back as `0xC0000142 (-1073741502)`, which means something like "failed to load DLL" or something. Running anything under the system32 path, even with privileged user credentials, is going to run into oddball issues with permissions, again due to the initialization procedure for creating a process.

Basically, the `Process.Start` flow looks something like this:

(assumptions: UserA == process running w3wp, UserB == impersonation ctx, UserC == credentials specified in process start info)

1. First, UserB isn't going to have much impact, as we've discussed in other conversations; any process creation stuff is going to be based on the ***process token*** of the "launching entity", so the credentials of UserA are the ones we'll be looking at.
2. The runtime says "Hey, can UserA access the file name specified in `StartInfo.FileName`?"
3. Windows responds yes/no, but also "BUT, to use that, you also need to be able to read all these other DLLs"
4. Runtime responds "Ok, can UserA access those DLLs?"
5. If the answer to all the above is yes, then the runtime says "Ok, logon this user and try creating a new process with cmd line and arguments..."

You are most-likely running into issues with either #2 or #4, as the default app pool identity has no read-access rights to the System32 folder. This is why when you switch the identity of the w3wp process to a privileged account, it works.

You could try a couple things, but the easiest option is probably switching back to a low-privilege account (like default app pool identity), but grant read-only access to the system32 folder to that account.

I would **ABSOLUTELY** not run w3wp as a privileged user, though - that is just asking for massive headaches should anything nasty happen, like somebody hacking you.

Oh, last thoughts:

- **DON'T** set `UseShellExecute` to true if you can help it, it does weird stuff.
- **DON'T** set `LoadUserProfile` to true if you can help it, it also does weird stuff, and is really slow as well.
- **DO** set `CreateNoWindow` to true if you can, otherwise you'll see lotsa windows opening/closing on the server
- **DO** use `RedirectStandardOutput / RedirectStandardError` instead of piping the output, it's way more controllable and gives better feedback when things go wrong.
- **DO** always check the ExitCode of the process if it doesn't look like it worked

Comment: Everyone full control , as i mentioned

Comment: p.s. , and of course Thank you VERY much for your effort solving this issue  of myne !

Comment: it is coming back with 0xC0000142 in the event viewer. ( but as i mentioed - everyone is full access in the `c:\windows\*.* /s`)

Comment: Event viewer `Application popup: cmd.exe - Application Error : The application was unable to start correctly (0xc0000142). Click OK to close the application. ` Also I've already read this  :http://asprosys.blogspot.co.uk/2009/03/perils-and-pitfalls-of-launching.html

Comment: @RoyiNamir Did you try using Process Monitor? It should tell you at exactly what point the call to create the new process failed.

Comment: of course. it said "page is read only" or something like that. and the event viewer showed the error 2 comments up.I had to leave it the f*** alone. I spent a week about this issue. as I said the solution is that both w3wp user and both username should be the same.(doesnt have to be admin)....p.s. I have NO IDEA why high user A cant run process with HIGH user B.

Comment: Strange...It *should* only require read/execute rights. One idea to try would be to move a copy of whatever you're trying to run into some low-security folder (like a temp folder) and try running it from there...

Comment: In reality Im running pgp.exe (which encrypts decrypts). and It is on the progam files. and ofcurse - everyone full control /s. still....nope. ( and im not running it with cmd , Im running it straight as the command name).

Comment: p.s. there is a big chance it will work with xp. I believe in win7 they changed something related to security(obviously)